# Gauss Jordan elimination reduces to row-echelon form always?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text:

[image]

and I'm wondering if gauss-jordan elimination always leads to an identity matrix on the left? If so, that helps me understand this passage:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out why [A 0] can be rewritten as [I 0]. Why is this?

Comment: Yes, G-J always leads to the identity matrix provided that the solution set is unique.

Comment: This algorithm always ends at row echelon form. Whether or not that means a full rank identity matrix on the left depends on the initial conditions. Yes if the original matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of terminology is familiar to you, but one way to see this is by talking about the [pivot positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_element#Pivot_position) (wikipedia link).  If $A$ is an invertible square matrix, then $A$ has a pivot position in every row.  This is because there is a unique solution to $Ax = b$ for every $b$.  But if $A$ is a square matrix with a pivot in every row, that means $A$ is row-equivalent to the identity matrix $I$.  That means $[A \;0]$ can be rewritten as $[I\; 0]$ using row operations.

Answer (score 1):

Gauss-Jordan elimination leads to identity matrix if the equation system has a unique solution. Book gives an example when this is the case so here is an example when this is not the case:

**Example:** Take the equation system
$$x+y+z = 2$$
$$x+y = 1$$
$$z = 2$$

which has no solution and can be represented as
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z \\
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    1 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}, \text{where }A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Here, notice that in order to find solution of this equation system, we need to multiply both sides of the equation by $A^{-1}$ from the left. However, applying Gauss-Jordan elimination,

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

so as you can see, we cannot have identity matrix by using row elementary operations. When it can be done, i.e. $A$ is invertible, we can say $[A\ \ 0]$ can be written as $[I\ \ 0]$ since they are row equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Gauss-Jordan eliminition works if and only if an inverse exists. It doesn't work for the null element matrix (matrix of zeros).

They said that [A 0] can be rewritten as [I 0] **using elementary row operations** so there are operations so that works.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. Gauss-Jordan elimination *always* works. You end up with the identity matrix if and only if the original matrix is nonsingular (is square with maximum rank). The zero matrix is already in reduced echelon form :)

Comment: Gauss-Jordan can be applied to uninvertible matrix, but it doesn't work as it doesn't accomplish its goal that is to find an inverse. If you consider that its goal is to find the rank, row echelon form ... etc, then yes, my sentence is wrong. However, I still say that it works if a unique solution exists, in the sense that I meant it.